# Find the line with a positive slope that is tangent to two circles

Tags: circles, implicit-differentiation

There is a line with positive slope which is tangent to the circle x^2+y^2=1 at some point P and which is also tangent to the circle $(x-3)^2 + y^2 = 4$ at a point Q. Find the equation of this line.

Comment: What have you tried? In order for other users to better aid you, you should share what your thoughts on the problem are and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are some neat ways to think about this question. I strongly recommend you draw a picture.

Let $L_1$ be a line tangent to the first circle at a point $P_{12}$. Let $L_3$ be the line parallel to $L_1$ through the origin, and $L_2$ and $L_4$ be the lines perpendicular to $L_1$ through the origin and $(3,0)$ respectively. Let $P_{ij}$ be the intersection between lines $L_i$ and $L_j$. The four lines described form a rectangle, with side lengths 1 along $L_2$ and $L_4$. If $L_1$ is also tangent to the second circle, then the distance between $P_{34}$ and the center $(3,0)$ is equal to 1 (the radius 2 minus the side length 1 along $L_4$).

Now we actually compute with coordinates. Suppose the equation for $L_3$ is $y=mx$, so the equation for $L_4$ is $y = -\frac{1}{m}(x - 3)$. The intersection is $P_{34} = \left(\frac{3}{m^2+1}, \frac{3m}{m^2+1}\right)$. We can use the known distance between $P_{34}$ and $(3,0)$ to solve for $m$:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{9m^4}{(m^2+1)^2} + \frac{9m^2}{(m^2+1)^2}} &= 1 \\
\frac{3m}{\sqrt{m^2+1}} &= 1 \\
8m^2 &= 1 \\
m &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
Now $P_{12}$ is 1 unit along the line $y = -2\sqrt{2}x$ (in the 4th quadrant), so it's $\left(-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)$. Finally, $L_1$ has the equation
$$y - \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(x + \frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ at some point $p(h,k)$ is $hx+ky=1$.

If this tangent is also a tangent to the circle ${(x-3)}^2+y^2=4$ then

The perpendicular distance of $hx+ky=1$ from the center of the circle ${(x-3)}^2+y^2=4$ = The radius of the circle ${(x-3)}^2+y^2=4$

i.e., 
            $\frac{3h+0.k-1}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}= 2$

Squaring on both sides,

$\frac{{(3h-1)}^2}{h^2+k^2}=4$

But we know that $p:(h,k)$ lies on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ therefore, $h^2+k^2=1$

The equation becomes, 
${(3h-1)}^2=4$ or, $9h^2-6h+1=4$ or, $9h^2-6h-3=0$ $(h-1)(9h+3)=0$ i.e, $h=1,-\frac{1}{3}$ correspondingly $k= 0,\pm \frac{2\sqrt2 }{3}$

Therefore the point $p:(h,k)$  are $(1,0)$ or $(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2\sqrt2 }{3} )$ or $(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{2\sqrt2 }{3} )$

Now the slope of the tangent $hx+ky=1$ is $-\frac{h}{k}$ is given positive.

Therefore, $P:(h,k):=(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2\sqrt2 }{3} )$

And the tangent of the equation is $-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2\sqrt2 }{3}y=1$ i.e., $x-2\sqrt2 y+3=0$